# API token generation for Symfony2

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, oauth

I am in the process of development of **REST API** server using **Symfony2** framework. Following bundles have been added already and are in use:

- FOSRestBundle
- FOSUserBundle
- JMSSerializerBundle

  Basically what I need to **add** is **token generation logic** so that user can receive token after authentication and use it for future API calls. I have already tried FOSOAuthServerBundle but there is one additional step during authorization for granting Client permissions. I do not need this step since I will not provide ability to register oAuth client. I will just have website and most likely mobile app for communicating with the REST server.

  Do I need ***FOSOAuthServerBundle*** in this case? Or is there a better approach (e.g. create customer authentication provider as described at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)? If I should go with FOSOAuthServerBundle, how can I skip a step for confirmation of granting access for oAuth Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have finally found the answer under another question - [Symfony2+FOSOAuthServerBundle: Browser-less initial authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624933/symfony2fosoauthserverbundle-browser-less-initial-authentication)

Basically **FOSOAuthServerBundle** can be used with grand type **GRANT_TYPE_USER_CREDENTIALS** (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/oauth2-php/blob/master/lib/OAuth2/OAuth2.php#L182)

Detailed explanation of **grand types** was found at http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF66/Grant+Type+Parameters